# What does absolute sign mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example

```
func(@param) do |f|
    some code here
end
```

and

```
@param.each do |sth|
    some code here
end
```

What does the absolute value sign do here? I don't understand these two pieces of code.

Comment: It's just syntax to introduce block parameters (similar to how parenthesis, in the appropriate location, introduce method parameters). Search for "ruby block tutorial".

Comment: I fail to see how this question is too localized, when it is so much like all the other "What does ..... mean in Ruby" questions over to the side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the local variable within the block, so for the line:

```
@param.each do |sth|
```

you're iterating over `@param` right, well each item in `@param` is referred to singularly as `sth`.

So if `@param` refers to an array containing the numbers

```
[1,3,5,4]
```

During the first iteration `sth` will be `1`, then `3`, then `5`, then `4`.

Same goes for :

```
func(@param) do |f|
```

except now the local variable is called `f`! You could call it anything you want, even `|ihavenoideawhatimdoing|`

Comment: what if the return value of fund(@param) is not a set of values but one single value? Does it still work?

Comment: yes, it will just iterate over the variable once. For a list of n values, it will iterate over it n times, one for `each` value

Answer (score 3):

It's a local variable, it is saying that for the block of code between `do`...`end`, the variable `f` is defined.

Comment: Then how does it know what f and sth are? I've not assigned any value to them yet.

Comment: @user1229490 the method you are calling gives you that value, you are just giving it a name. And in ruby that's called a block

Comment: So the return value of the previous function is assigned to |f|. Is that right?

Comment: @user1229490 "It depends". In this case, see `Enumerable#each`/`Array#each` (in rdoc) - however, it is very dependent upon the type of the receiver.

Comment: it can be a anything, and many times! for the `each` example, if `@params = [1,2,3]`, your block of code will run 3 times, first with `sth = 1`, then `sth = 2` and then `sth = 3`

Answer (score 2):

It is a parameter to a block. The block is the part of the code between the do and the end. That block of code can use `f` or `sth`, which in your examples would probably have been set by `func` or `each`.

A [tutorial on Ruby blocks](http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/?Chapter=10) will probably be helpful.

[Labmda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) - more abstract, but it was the context in which I first saw these things.

Comment: I wouldn't bring in lambda calculus .. however, this answer does say what it is (or rather, what it introduces) .. there are also much better tutorials for blocks available.

Comment: Yeah, lambda calculus is over the top, and not a great comparison because blocks, unlike lambda expressions, can have multiple parameters. Better terms to drop would have been anonymous functions or first-class functions.

Answer (score 0):

It signifies instance variables. You often see it interchanged if people are using **attr_*** methods like **attr_accessor**, which makes **@someattr** and **self.some_attr** equivalent in instance methods.

Comment: It does not signify instance variables and does not relate to `attr*`: `@isAnInstanceVariable`.